# How to get the key of an object array if the value is true

Tags: javascript

I have an object. I want to get the keys if the value is true.

What I have tried :

```js
const data = [{superadmin: true, admin: false, user: false}]
keys = Object.keys(data).filter(k => data[k]);
console.log(typeof(data));
console.log(data)
console.log(keys)
```

Expected Output :

```
["superadmin"]
```

Comment: why an array? why not only the object?

Comment: @NinaScholz my backend data structure is like this

Comment: what if oyu have more than one item/object in the array?

Comment: Your keys are in `data[0]` not `data` - you'll need to iterate over `data`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
const data = [{
  superadmin: true,
  admin: false,
  user: false
}]
keys = data.map(obj => {
  const data = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
    return !!obj[key]
  })

  return data
}).flat(1);

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given code

```
keys = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(k => data[0][k] === true);
```

should work.

Comment: I did edit the answer - please try now

Comment: Then your input data is not what you put in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead returning value, you simply assign the keys with a value of `true` to a variable, like this

```js
const data = [{superadmin: true, admin: false, user: false}]
let mkeys
data.map((obj) => {
  mkeys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k])
})
console.log(mkeys)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple:

```
let keys=[];
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)){
    if (data[key]) keys.push(key)
}
console.log(keys)
```

If you want one line:

```
keys = Object.keys(data).filter(k => data[k]);
```